# a question about functional analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Could you please help me to prove the following:

> Let $f$ be any non-zero functional on a vector space $X$ and $x_0$ is a fixed element of $X\setminus N(f)$, where $N(f)$ is the kernel of $f$. Show that any $x\in X$ has a unique representation $x = ax_0 + y$, $y\in N(f)$.

Comment: What have you tried? You have to prove two things: that every $x$ has such a representation, and that no $x$ has two such representations. Can you prove either?

Comment: Well I tried something but I couldnt understand where I failed.If you can,could you please send me the whole solution ? So that I can compare my solution.

Answer (score 1):

- If $x\in X$ then $x-\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0\in N(f)$ (why?)...
- If $x = a_1x_0 + y_1= a_2x_0 + y_2$ then $ (a_1-a_2)x_0 + (y_1-y_2)\in N(f)$ ...
   since $(ax_0\in N(f)\iff a=0) \Longrightarrow$ ...

Comment: why does $y_1$ have to equal $y_2$? they both end up in $N(f)$

Comment: oh $a_1 = a_2$. Then setting $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be $f(x)/f(x_0)$ forces both $y_1$ and $y_2$ to be $x - f(x) /f(x_0)x_0$. right?

Comment: @yoshi Actually if we set $a=a_1=a_2$ then $y_1=x-ax_0=y_2$.